# Only allow one React Accordion to be expanded at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of data that will be used to create accordions, I'd like to make it so that only one of them can be expanded at once (i.e, if the user expands accordion #1 and then #2, #1 will un-expand)

I have this code:

```js
const MyAccordion = props => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState()
    const handleChange = panel => (_, isExpanded) => {setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false)}
    const classes = styles //?
    let accordionInfo = createAccordionInfo(props.propthing);
    return (
        <Accordion
            key={accordionInfo.uid}
            onChange={handleChange(accordionInfo.uid)}
            expanded={expanded === accordionInfo.uid}
            TransitionProps={{unmountOnExit: true}}
            className={classes.accordion}
        >
            <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} aria-controls={`${accordionInfo.uid}-content`} id={`${accordionInfo.uid}-header`}>
                <Typography>Accordion Summary</Typography>
            </AccordionSummary>

            <AccordionDetails>
                <Typography>Accordion Details</Typography>
            </AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
    )
}

const MyAccordions = props => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState()
    const handleChange = panel => (_, isExpanded) => {setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false)}
    return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
            {accordions.map(accordion => (
                <MyAccordion onChange={handleChange} propthing={accordion} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I'm quite new to React so I suspect I've made a mistake with the states. Any help / tips would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you tried putting state and handlers in both the parent `MyAccordions` and the children `MyAccordion` components. If you want only one accordion open at-a-time then I suggest placing the state in the parent component so it can manage what is open/expanded. Use the children accordion ids as the basis of determining which should expand.

Parent

```
const MyAccordions = props => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = id => (_, isExpanded) => {
    // if expanded, set id to open/expand, close it otherwise 
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? id: null);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
      {accordions.map(accordion => {
        const info = createAccordionInfo(accordion);
        return (
          <MyAccordion
            key={info.uid} // <-- set React key here!!
            onChange={handleChange(info.uid)}
            expanded={expanded === info.uid}
          />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child

```
const MyAccordion =({ expanded, onChange }) => {
  const classes = styles //?

  return (
    <Accordion
      onChange={onChange}
      expanded={expanded}
      TransitionProps={{unmountOnExit: true}}
      className={classes.accordion}
    >
      <AccordionSummary
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls={`${accordionInfo.uid}-content`}
        id={`${accordionInfo.uid}-header`}
      >
        <Typography>Accordion Summary</Typography>
      </AccordionSummary>

      <AccordionDetails>
        <Typography>Accordion Details</Typography>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks for the response, I'm afraid that the accordions are now not expanding at all :/

Comment: @kougami Ok, might just need some tweaking. What component library are you using, Material-ui? Do you already have a running codesandbox or similar that we could examine?

Comment: No problem, I figured it out - I changed "setExpanded(isExpanded ? null : id);" to "setExpanded(isExpanded ? id : false);" and it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: @kougami Ah, and you know what... that was probably the line I guessed the most on, it wasn't clear (*to me*) what the value of `isExpanded` represented, so it must be what the accordion says it *should* be, not what it was. I suspect you could use `null` instead of `false`, but since they're both falsey it would still work. Sorry for any confusion I may've caused.

Comment: It's all good :) you're right, it's not too clear what isExpanded is supposed to represent, but I'm too new to React to have a good understanding of it, I think. This is something I've hashed together after looking at the various examples on the MUI site.

Comment: @kougami Right, totally. Since it seems to hint at updating the state to be "expanded" then perhaps a name like `shouldExpand` might make the meaning a little clearer if/when you come back and revisit the code. Cheers and good luck.